# Animated circular countdown timer using HTML, CSS, or javascript

Tags: jquery, css, html, webkit

I want to create a circle that is sectioned into 4 quarters, and each quarter is then sub-divided into segments. Each quarter will have a different background colour (or background image).
The circle will serve as a countdown timer, where each segment will last around 5 seconds (see attached image for idea of what I'm looking for). The timer will only start when a javascript command has been issued (it should also be possible to pause, and rewind the timer).

[image]

The transition between the segments does not have to be a smooth animation (i.e. transitioning to a segment can simply involve the previous segment background colour turning white)

There are a few caveats:
- The **number of segments in each quadrant can change**, so the size of each segment has to be flexible
- The **order of quadrants can change** (i.e. instead of blue, orange, red, green... we could have orange, red, purple, etc etc)
- **It has to work on iPhone and existing Android phones** (I was looking at Raphael and SVG, but this doesn't seem to be supported on Android.)

I'm at a loss at how best to tackle this problem, so would be grateful to hear suggestions or even see examples (although I haven't been able to source any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way of achieving the result you want is to use a **canvas** element and draw on it by using javascript or to use animated images along with static images and a little JS to switch between the two types.

Comment: Yeah probably. It's too bad there isn't something similar out there that can start me off :) (the closest thing I can find to what I'm trying to do is http://m.brujula.net/util/abstracttimer/)

Comment: @Peter It's not that hard to have something like that, using the canvas element, triangles and some really basic trigonometry. Aftear learning to do it with triangles you can challenge yourself with arcs and you'll get the job done. See the [HTML5 Canvas](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/) specs for details..

Comment: handy page ... will look into this.

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen [Raphaël JS](http://raphaeljs.com/)? Its really geared to graphs. I'm not really sure of the specifics, but this should get you started.

Comment: yep as mentioned originally I was looking at Raphael and SVG, but they don't seem to work in Android